# How to access to every single element in WP Posts

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Im trying to customize my html structure in a WP post but i dont have access to them, here is an example :
lets say i have this post but i want the the img to be col-6 and text col-6 both together col-12 but i dont have access to any html structure for posts and the code editor in wP's post section dosent work.
Thanks.

Comment: Could you explain what you do have access to? The child theme folder? single.php? style.css? functions.php? Could you say what 'doesn't work' means in relation to WPs code editor? Do you actually want to change the HTML structure or only the styling?

Comment: I have access to single.php which contains codes to summon full content of the post and my style page is style.css and my functions.php and when i write a new code in word press post section after trying to update so the codes i wore work it dosent apply the changes. and i want to change an alter the structure of the WP post styling is almost good if i cloud change the html on posts without using WP post code editor it would be fine . thanks

Comment: So can you FTP (e.g. through Filezilla or similar application) to put up a new single.php or style.css?

Answer (score 0):

Hi @johna you can access a single post element using default function of wp use this function for get single post element is_single()

```
function is_single( $post = '' ) {
global $wp_query;

if ( ! isset( $wp_query ) ) {
    _doing_it_wrong( __FUNCTION__, __( 'Conditional query tags do not work before the query is run. Before then, they always return false.' ), '3.1.0' );
    return false;
}

return $wp_query->is_single( $post );
```

}

Comment: So after applying this code to function.php what then how and where will i gain the access , sorry tho im new at this thanks .